# Oracle EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not display output

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have written below pivot query but it is not showing any output rows.
It just shows PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
DECLARE 
    expression CLOB;
BEGIN 

SELECT LISTAGG('''' || MONTH || ''' AS "' || MONTH || '"', ', ')
    INTO expression
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH FROM USER_AGREEMENT);

expression:= 'SELECT *
 FROM (
        SELECT AGGREMENTID, MONTH, AMOUNT
        FROM USER_AGREEMENT
    )
    PIVOT (
        SUM(AMOUNT)
        FOR MONTH IN (' || expression ||')
    )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE expression;
END;
```

I tried using DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(expression); but it doesn't work.

Comment: I good starting point is to read the documentation about it, you will know that it definitely doesn't output anything *directly* : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

Comment: In general, PL/SQL isn't designed to do visible output. The DBMS_OUTPUT package can be used for some things, but its primary purpose is troubleshooting messages. If you're hoping for formatted output like you'd get from sqlplus with native SQL, you're going to be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` executes a statement; it does not display anything.

If you want to display something then you need to use `DBMS_OUTPUT` and loop through the values from the statement:

```sql
DECLARE 
  expression CLOB;
  cur        SYS_REFCURSOR;
  id         USER_AGREEMENT.AGGREMENTID%TYPE;
  amount1    USER_AGREEMENT.AMOUNT%TYPE;
  amount2    USER_AGREEMENT.AMOUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
         || 'SELECT *
             FROM (
               SELECT AGGREMENTID, MONTH, AMOUNT
               FROM USER_AGREEMENT
             )
             PIVOT (
               SUM(AMOUNT)
               FOR MONTH IN ('
         || LISTAGG('''' || MONTH || ''' AS "' || MONTH || '"', ', ')
         || '))'
  INTO   expression
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH FROM USER_AGREEMENT);

  OPEN cur FOR expression;

  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO id, amount1, amount2;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(id || ', ' || amount1 || ', ' || amount2);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or:

```sql
DECLARE 
  TYPE id_tab     IS TABLE OF USER_AGREEMENT.AGGREMENTID%TYPE;
  TYPE amount_tab IS TABLE OF USER_AGREEMENT.AMOUNT%TYPE;
  expression CLOB;
  ids        id_tab;
  amount1s   amount_tab;
  amount2s   amount_tab;
BEGIN 
  SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
         || 'SELECT *
             FROM (
               SELECT AGGREMENTID, MONTH, AMOUNT
               FROM USER_AGREEMENT
             )
             PIVOT (
               SUM(AMOUNT)
               FOR MONTH IN ('
         || LISTAGG('''' || MONTH || ''' AS "' || MONTH || '"', ', ')
         || '))'
  INTO   expression
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT MONTH FROM USER_AGREEMENT);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE expression
    BULK COLLECT INTO ids, amount1s, amount2s;

  FOR i IN 1 .. ids.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ids(i) || ', ' || amount1s(i) || ', ' || amount2s(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_agreement (aggrementid, month, amount) AS
SELECT 1, 'January',  LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'February', LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'January',  LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Both output:

> ```
> 1, 6, 3
> 2, 15,
> ```

---

However, if you know that there are only going to be 12 different months then you probably do not need a dynamic query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT AGGREMENTID, MONTH, AMOUNT
  FROM USER_AGREEMENT
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(AMOUNT)
  FOR MONTH IN (
    'January'   AS January,
    'February'  AS February,
    'March'     AS March,
    'April'     AS April,
    'May'       AS May,
    'June'      AS June,
    'July'      AS July,
    'August'    AS August,
    'September' AS September,
    'October'   AS October,
    'November'  AS November,
    'December'  AS December
  )
)
```

Which outputs:

| AGGREMENTID | JANUARY | FEBRUARY | MARCH | APRIL | MAY | JUNE | JULY | AUGUST | SEPTEMBER | OCTOBER | NOVEMBER | DECEMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 3 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 15 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G2TLNY6d)

Comment: For first 2 queries I am getting ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - ORA-06512.
3rd query is fine, but i want to make the expression dynamic as for other usecase I have to operate on years rather than months.

Comment: @Sam SQL (including Oracle's dialect) is intended to have a fixed, pre-defined set of columns. Using dynamic SQL is not easy. Instead it is often better to use static SQL and then perform any transformations pivoting the data in whatever third-party language (i.e. C, Java, Python, C#, PHP, etc.) that you are using to connect to the database.

Comment: @Sam Regarding your issues with the first two queries. They both work in the linked fiddle; if they don't work for you then you need to work out what is different between the fiddle and your setup and once you work out what the difference is then that is probably going to be the reason why it does not work. We can't easily help with that as we do not have access to your tables; if you cannot solve it then you will need to share a [MRE] that replicates the problem.